# Highcharts stacked area filtering

Tags: highcharts

I'm getting a bug in my stacked area implementation when a user filters to a specific line.

In the image linked below, you'll see we're tracking two trends. When I turn off the "Dialup" trend, the orange area should remain where it is. Instead, it moves up to fill the entire area. Likewise, if I were to turn off the orange "Broadband" trend, the green dialup area fills the entire area below it, rather than falling to the baseline as it should.

[image]

(stackoverflow will not allow me to post images yet.)

You can see the value in the tooltip remains accurate.

Could anyone provide some insight into what may be causing this? In case this may be a factor, the chart is generated based on a table of data using Highcharts.visualize().

Comment: It seems weird - is your stacking set correctly? This example shows how it is supposed to work: http://jsfiddle.net/3VT3p/. Can you modify that to display your issue?

Comment: I tried my best to recreate it in jfiddle, but our implementation is a little odd and built into our WordPress instance. You can see a live version here: http://www.pewresearch.org/data-trend/media-and-technology/internet-penetration/ But I'm not sure if that will help.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you're using Highcharts 3.0.0. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16826963/highcharts-no-longer-animates-and-readjusts-rescales-chart-upon-addition-and-rem), there was a bug in this version of Highcharts. If you upgrade Highcharts to the latest version, it should work as intended.