# Highcharts no longer animates and readjusts/rescales chart upon addition and removal of series in legend after upgrading to jQuery 1.10

Tags: jquery, highcharts

After upgrading to jQuery version 1.10, Highcharts no longer animates and readjusts/rescales chart upon addition and removal of series in legend.

With jQuery 1.9, when I click on an item in the legend, the corresponding series will be removed and the chart will animate and rescale. See the link below for the demo chart as provided by Highcharts.

**jsfiddle (using jQuery 1.9):**
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-labels/

However, when the jquery version is set to 1.10, this behavior seems to have broken. See the link below for the same chart but using jQuery 1.10.

**jsfiddle (using jQuery 1.10):**
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.10.0/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/spline-irregular-time/

My Chrome console keeps showing `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'opacity' in cursor:default;padding:0;white-space:nowrap;` error but I still can't figure it out. Has anyone encountered the same problem?

Comment: I have the exact same issue and I'm also looking for a solution. But I think we have to wait for corrected version of highcharts.

Comment: Same problem with jQuery 2.0.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was known bug, but according to github, it should be fixed in master branch http://github.highcharts.com/master/highcharts.src.js

https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1881

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The master branch copy has indeed fixed the bug when I use Chrome. But in Firefox, it still doesn't work and the console shows "NS_ERROR_FAILURE: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIDOMWindow.getComputedStyle]". Is there a better solution?

Comment: Fortunately the new version of Highcharts has been released. Have updated the JS file and everything works like a charm now.