# rCharts shows limited functionality when used with Shiny 0.8.0.99

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny, rcharts

updating to the latest Shiny development version 0.8.0.99 seems to had some negative side effects for my charts created via rCharts (version 0.4.2). In particular, I've found the following two issues using Highcharts in my Shiny apps:

- Tooltip texts do not disappear once activated via hovering
- Automatic rescaling of the x/y-axis does not work if a series is activated/deactivated

Below you will find a small reproducible example reusing Ramanth's Highchart example from his [GitHub page](https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts).

This is the standalone Highchart code which works perfectly fine:

```
library(rCharts)

h1 <- Highcharts$new()
h1$chart(type = "spline")
h1$series(data = c(1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 4, 6, 2, 3, 5, NA), dashStyle = "longdash")
h1$series(data = c(NA, 4, 1, 3, 4, 2, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4), dashStyle = "shortdot")
h1$legend(symbolWidth = 80)
h1
```

You should encounter the problems described above if you embed the same code in a minimal Shiny app:

```
library(shiny)
library(rCharts)

runApp(list(
  ui = basicPage(
    h2("Ramnath's GitHub example"),
    showOutput('myChart', 'highcharts')
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$myChart <- renderChart({
      h1 <- Highcharts$new()
      h1$chart(type = "spline")
      h1$series(data = c(1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 4, 6, 2, 3, 5, NA), dashStyle = "longdash")
      h1$series(data = c(NA, 4, 1, 3, 4, 2, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4), dashStyle = "shortdot")
      h1$legend(symbolWidth = 80)
      # Set dom attribute otherwise chart will not appear on the web page
      h1$set(dom = 'myChart')
      h1
    })
  }
))
```

I know that I've used the latest development version of Shiny and not the latest stable version. Therefore I have no guarantee that everything works as expected. However, I would be interested if someone has found a solution/workaround for this problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is related to the use of `jQuery 1.10.1` in the development version of Shiny. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16826963/highcharts-no-longer-animates-and-readjusts-rescales-chart-upon-addition-and-rem) to understand details.

I will update `highcharts` from the master branch on `github` later this week and that should solve this issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer and additional information! Looking forward to the update. Unfortunately my rep is too small to vote your answer up. :-)

Comment: A quick way to use it right now is to set `options(rcharts.cdn = TRUE)` in your shiny code. This delivers js/css assets from the highcharts cdn, which are up-to-date.